# CSS3 Slide Up and Slide Down with Fixed Flex div

Tags: html, css, css-animations

At certain points in my app I am adding and removing a class `is-visible` (slide in) and `is-hidden` (slide down).

I have a fixed div at the bottom of the page using flex. However, my animations don't quite work, as it only slides down half way and leaves half the content on show.

As for the slide back up, well it doesn't slide up at all.

Here's a demo, if you inspect the code and just add the above class names onto the `sticky` dive you'll see what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/4v36pbdy/

Are my animations wrong? I'm confused and stumped why it's not working. It should slide down when the hidden class is added and slide up when its got the visible class?

Here is the code:

```
.sticky {
  background: #f5f5f5;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 444;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    & .left {
      flex-basis: 52%;
    }
    & .right {
      flex: 1 1;
    }
    &.is-hidden {
      max-height: 0;
    }
    &.is-visible {
      max-height: 78px;
      transition-property: all;
      transition-duration: 0.5s;
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1, 0.5, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Here's a demo, if you inspect the code ..." – I think you forgot the link. Also, only use the specific property, and not just `all` because that will loop through all possible animatable objects.

Comment: Hi, sorry, link is now attached: https://jsfiddle.net/4v36pbdy/

Answer (score 0):

I created an inner wrapper inside `sticky` and moved the padding property into that rather than the outer container and also added `overflow: hidden`